# Fade effect ONLY on new elements

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

I have this CSS on some messages in a Ui I'm working on.

```
opacity: 0;
animation-name: fadeIn;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-delay: 0.3s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;


@keyframes fadeIn {
   0% {
       opacity: 0;
   }
   100% {
       opacity: 1;
   }
}
```

It fades in new items. Works great EXCEPT.... it fades ALL messages when the page loads. I ONLY want messages to fade in if they are NEW. Imagine a new message coming into an existing list.

Is there a way to tweak this animation to not trigger on page load? I could probably rig something with JS, but was curious if there is a pure CSS way to do this.

Comment: So you want the messages that are already stored somewhere to be displayed at page load without any fading, and new messages that pops in while the page is active will fade in one by one? What if you add a class to the dynamic messages that is not applied to the static ones?

Comment: I could potentially let the original tickets load, then add an additional style on them with JS. But was wondering if there is a simpler way to do that

Answer (score 0):

We gotta find a way to tell css which are new and which are old... we could use a property within the object perhaps?

**js** where we set the class based on the status field being 'new' or otherwise:

```
dataSet.map((item, key) => {
        return (
          <div className={item.status === "new" ? "newClass" : "oldClass"}>
            {item.name} - {item.status}
          </div>
        );
      })
```

sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pbgryx?file=Messages.js)